# Is it a good idea to always set the underlying type in enums?

Tags: c++

I've gotten into a habit of always setting the underlying type of my enums. Most of the enums I create have a small amount of elements, so I usually set the type to uint8_t.

```
enum class E : uint8_t {...};
```

From code generation efficiency, is this a good thing to do? or would it be better to leave the type unspecified and letting the compiler use its default.

I know we're talking about minuscule deltas in speed but, since it's about picking a default behavior, may as well default to the slightly faster, if applicable.

The reason for asking is that, while learning some x64 assembly, I learned that the ah/al registers are slightly slower than their bigger counterparts.

Comment: explicitly stating the underlying type will improve compatibility if you are sure about the values range.

Comment: Start with the most restrictive option because it will cause fewer surprises. Then profile and see if it really is a problem. If it is a significant problem, consider changing. If you change profile again and see if the difference is worth it.

Comment: In your enum `E`, if you define an element out of range of `uint8_t`, a compile error will be generated. So as my understanding, if you need to change the enum a lot, or you write many elements in your enum, setting the underlying type may be better.

Comment: I will not speak to efficiency, although I doubt this would be measurable. But the assumption that the compiler can choose the best default is faulty. On some platforms, the choice of underlying type for enums without a fixed type was made long ago and cannot change (old code that assumed that type must link with new code). A second notable factor is that in C++, it's far easier to run into UB with an enum without fixed type, even if you use the *exact same type* the compiler would choose. Therefore, it's definitely advisable to specify it.